# Given an array of child components, how to access their state data from parent component?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have a 2D array as a state in a parent component, which represents a grid. The outer array is a array of < div /> containers and The inner array contains GridItem components, which represents the cells on the grid. The GridItem components have state data such as nodeType, nodeWeight etc..

I want to iterate through the 2d array and get the state values of each GridItem for further processing.

The problem:
I cannot access/Get the state values directly from parent component by iterating the array of GridItems.
`e.g console.log(this.state.gridState[0].props.children[0]) <- returns the GridItem but it's state and other than passed prop values are inaccessible;`

I Tried writing a callback method for the child components class, but I don't think there's a way to "activate" this callback from parent component. Though I managed to write a callback for setting GridItem values whenever they were clicked.
I also tried using refs, but figured out it might not be wise to use refs for 1000+ components in an array.

I'm still very new to react, which is why I think there might be something fundamentally wrong with my way of coding this. Can I even store these components in an array or should I do this some other way?
Grid.jsx (only necessary methods)

```js
class Grid extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gridRowCount: 35,
            gridColCount: 72,
            gridState: [],
        };
        this.gridWasClicked = this.gridWasClicked.bind(this);
    }
    initGrid(){                    
        let counter = 0;
        for(let i = 1; i < this.state.gridRowCount+1; i++)
        {
            let tmpRow = [];
            for(let j = 1; j < this.state.gridColCount+1; j++)
            {
                tmpRow.push(<GridItem key={counter} gridIndex={[j, i]} gridWasClicked={this.gridWasClicked}/>);
                counter++;
            }
            this.pushElemToGrid(<div key={counter} className="grid-row">{tmpRow}</div>);
        }
        this.iterateGrid();
    }
```

GridItem.jsx (only necessary methods)

```js
class GridItem extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isVisited: false,
            nodeWeigth: 0,
            gridIndex: [0,0],
            nodeType: 0,
        };

    }
    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.setState({gridIndex: [this.props.gridIndex[0], this.props.gridIndex[1]]});
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div className="grid-item" onClick={this.cellWasClicked}>
            {this.state.nodeType}
        </div>  
        );
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need state of `GreedItem` components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think in a different way about this - `GridItem` should be a 'dumb' component, 'controlled' by `Grid`; `Grid` controls `GridItem` by passing it props; `GridItem` "react"s to the props it is passed. Therefore, you don't really need to know `GridItem`'s state, specifically, just what props it is passed in any one moment, and `Grid` always knows that. So just control `GridItem` from `Grid` by way of props. Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. I was starting to realize that's the way React components are meant to be used. Thanks for confirmation and helpful answer!

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help! It's just because you're new to React - once it clicks you'll be fine